# Scraping with javascript begginer´s problem

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am writing my first code to scrape several newspapers notes articles, but it doesn't work.
I am not sure what the problem is. In the first part of the code I place in an array the links of the article, but then when I try to scrape every note it fails. If I pass an array with two links it works, so I guess it has sth to do with variable scopes or sth like that. If anyone can identify the problem that would be great. Thanks

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

const baseUrl = "https://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html/";
const numbers = Array.from({length: 2 + 1}, (_, i) => i);
const paginasCiudad = [];

for (const number of numbers) {
  paginasCiudad.push(baseUrl + number);
};
console.log(paginasCiudad);
console.log("posPag");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const urls = [];
    for (let pagina of paginasCiudad) {    
        await page.goto(pagina);
        const enlaces = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('article.big-entry-box a.cover-link, article.standard-entry-box a.cover-link, article.medium-entry a.cover-link');
            const links = [];

            for (let element of elements) {
                links.push(element.href);

const notas = [];            }
            
            return links;
        });
        enlaces.forEach(element => {
            urls.push(element);
        });   
        
    }
    //await browser.close();  
    console.log(urls);

    try {
        const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
            path: 'notas.csv',
            header: [
                {id: 'fecha', title: 'Fecha'},
                {id: 'titulo', title: 'Título'},
                {id: 'bajada', title: 'Bajada'},
                {id: 'nota', title: 'Nota'},
                {id: 'imagen', title: 'Imagen'},
                {id: 'seccion', title: 'Sección'},
                {id: 'tags', title: 'Tags'},
                {id: 'link', title: 'Link'},
                {id: 'fuente', title: 'Fuente'}
            ]
        });
  
        for (let url of urls) {
            try {
                const newData = {}; // objeto vacío
  
                await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });
      
                newData.fecha = await page.$eval('span.nota-fecha', el => el.textContent);
                newData.titulo = await page.$eval('h1.nota-title', el => el.textContent);
                newData.bajada = await page.$eval('div.nota-bajada', el => el.textContent);
                newData.nota = await page.$$eval('div.article-body p', els => els.map(el => el.textContent).join('\n'));
                newData.imagen = await page.$eval('picture.preview-img > div.extra-holder > img', el => el.getAttribute('src'));
                newData.seccion = await page.$eval('div.breadcrumbs.flex-container.align-center', el => el.textContent);
                newData.seccion2 = '';
                newData.tags = await page.$eval('div.tags-container.flex-container.flex-wrap', el => el.textContent);
                //newData.link = page.url();
                newData.link2 = '';
                newData.fuente = 'La Capital';
            
                const laCapital = [];
                laCapital.push(newData)
        
                await csvWriter.writeRecords(laCapital);
                console.log(newData);
                console.log(`Se ha guardado la nota en un archivo .csv llamado "notas.csv"AA`);
                } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                }
            }
            console.log(laCapital)
            console.log(`Se han guardado todas las notas en un archivo .csv llamado "notas.csv"BB`);
        } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        } finally {
    await browser.close();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: `https://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html/` is not a valid URL for starters

Comment: I get 187 links on the homepage `https://www.lacapital.com.ar/` so it is a matter of testing the URL you are accessing

Comment: Thanks!! https://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html/ is not valid, it only works when you add a number that refers to the number of page, for instance  https://www.lacapital.com.ar/secciones/laciudad.html/11 I do that in the first part of the code

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the urls array is properly populated with the article links. You can add a console log statement inside the enlaces.forEach() loop to confirm that the URLs are being added to the array correctly.

Check that the for...of loop that scrapes data from each URL is actually being executed. You can add a console log statement inside this loop to confirm that